# .exe compatibility layer?

Tags: windows, wine, playonlinux, compatibility

Is there a piece of software that will let me run .exe files as soon as I install the program, without having to go through a complicated process like Wine or PlayOnLinux makes me do? I would like to run Terraria on my Ubuntu system and I was hoping that there would be a simple way to do this.

Comment: What complicated process are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a piece of software that will let me run .exe files as soon as I install the program

Natively? That is called WINE or the add-on to it called PlayOnLinux.

> without having to go through a complicated process like Wine or PlayOnLinux makes me do?

No, that is what WINE was created for. PlayOnLinux is difficult and peculiar but I can not say it is complicated. In general PlayOnLinux requires you to follow specific instructions to the letter.

> I would like to run Terraria on my Ubuntu system and I was hoping that there would be a simple way to do this.

The simplest and most efficient way to play this is either over a dual boot system or using a Virtual Machine with a Windows installed in it. The only downside to a VM: it will be a bit slower.

---

If you really want this to run natively: it seems Terraria runs on Steam with wine. [Installation](https://tom-geiger.de/?p=319):

> Install wine and winetricks. Install Steam from the Website. This will update Steam and exit at 26%, Start Steam: This will update steam completely. After this,
>   log in.
>
> ```
> cd ~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/Steam
> wine Steam.exe
> ```
>
> Download Terraria and install. This will install XNA Redist as
>   well. Exit Steam.Start Terraria manually with wine
>
> ```
> cd .wine/drive_c/Program Files/Steam/steamapps/common/terraria
> wine Terraria.exe
> ```
>
> This will tell you that you need Mono for Windows.
>
> Install Mono 2.10 and 2.8 via winetricks. People have reported
>   there is no need to install xact and xinput. If you run into trouble
>   after this point, install them and see if it fixes the problem you
>   have.
>
> Start Terraria.exe again. (With wine and mono). You will be
>   told that it can’t find Microsoft.Xna.Framework.
>
> Install .NET 4 from the Full Installer from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17718)!
>
> ```
> wine dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe
> ```
>
> If you get a message that .NET is already installed, use
>   regedit to remove this Node: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\NET
>   Framework Setup\NDP\v4 Then return to Step 9 above.
>
> Copy .NET 4 Files to Terraria directory
>
> ```
> cd .wine/drive_c/Program Files/Steam/steamapps/common/terraria
> cp ~/.wine/drive_c/windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/* .
> ```
>
> Start steam and run Terraria

Untested.  Good luck with this and you will get it working natively but I still would suggest to keep away from WINE/POL and to prefer the dual boot method or to use a Virtual Machine.